# Get the rows selectable for telerik radgidview

Tags: xaml, telerik

I have a telerik:RadGridView. I heard that the [By default the row selection is disabled ( AllowRowSelect is False ).](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/selecting/selecting-rows/client-side-selecting-with-a-click)

TWO QUESTIONS:

1. Now in my ViewModel class, how to enable it if satisfying a condition say if count>0?
2. I want to select a row and raise an event to enable a button in the View. How?

Comment: The link you posted is for ASP.net. In WPF selection is enabled by default. But you can change the selection mode (single line, multiple lines)

Comment: @unkreativ, sorry. I remove the wpf tag.

Comment: I'm still confused if you are using the XAML one or the ASP.NET AJAX  one? You removed the WPF tag, but still have XAML and Silverlight. Can you confirm that you are using ASP.NET AJAX or XAML?

Comment: @LanceMcCarthy, forget asp.net ajax. Just pure xaml. The link maybe wrong. I can't find the property for the row selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the solution at http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgridview---click-event

```
  private void RadGridView_RowLoaded(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.RowLoadedEventArgs e)
  {
      var row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
      if (row != null)
      {
          row.AddHandler(GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
       new MouseButtonEventHandler(GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
      }
  }

  private void GridViewRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Hi");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the documentation for Selection](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/selection/basics) (this is the same for WPF or Silverlight).

You can also perform programmatic selection, there are [several examples here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/selection/programmatic-selection).

To be more specific, you can use the actual item to perform selection, not the row. For example, let's say you have a model `Car` and your view model has `ObervableCollection<Car> Cars`

You have the GridView bound to that collection:

```
<telerik:GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"/>
```

That means you can now make a selection using one of the items programmatically (say on a button click), like this would select the first item:

`MyGridView.SelectedItems.Add(viewmodel.Cars[0]);`

To answer your question about enabling and disabling the selection based on an expression or viewmodel property, you can use a converter because `SelectionMode` is an enum.

Let's say you have a viewmodel property named `CanSelect`

```
public CanSelect
{
   get
   {
      return canSelect;
   }
   set
   {
      if(value==canSelect)return;
      canSelect=value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Next, you create a converter:

```
public class MySelectionModeConverter
{
   public Convert(object value...)
   {
       //pick the selection mode that makes the most sense for you
       return (bool)value ? SelectionMode.Single : SelectionMode.None
   }
}
```

Now you can bind to that viewmodel property, something like this:

`<telerik:GridView SelectionMode="{Binding CanSelect, Converter={StaticResource MySelectionModeConverter}}" />`

Lastly, you stated that you want a RowClick event. this is not available in the GridView by default, generally you'd use `SelectionChanged`. You'll need to add your own `MouseDown` event on the GridViewRow.

Here's an example:

```
this.AddHandler(GridViewRow.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
             new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftDown), true);

public void OnMouseLeftDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)        
 {         }
```

Comment: I need an event when a row is selected. Can we add the property to the RadGridView? `SelectionChanged="RadGridView_RowLoaded"`. Then in code behind to implement the method?

Comment: SelectionChanging or SelectionChanged might be what you want, see here http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/events/selection-events

Comment: Not sure why SelectionChanged event is not working. But I noticed that SelectionChanged will only fire when the selected item is actually changed. What I want is by clicking the row then raise an event.

Comment: I added the code you want to add an event handler to the GridViewRow. Note that if you want double click, see the example app here http://www.telerik.com/forums/single-click-event-on-gridview-row

Comment: The thing is when I click any row, it repeatedly raises the event. Say 12 times it reaches the event code. Not sure why.